# Matlab Builder NE Integration

Tags: .net, matlab, matlab-deployment

I am looking to integrate my matlab code in a Visual Studio .NET application. I know I need to use Matlab Builder NE. However, I am not able to download or add matlab builder ne. How do I go about integrating matlab builder ne in my matlab. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you download MATLAB Builder NE?

Comment: I dont think it is a freeware ! so it would be of much help if i would get know of a way around that.. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure the MATLAB Builder NE toolbox is still supported by Mathworks. It's been subsumed under Matlab SDK. It's best feature is the deploytool. You can still create .NET assemblies in Matlab but it's a little more work, depending on your version.